# Building an .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I don't see where is the mistake in the next situation, I have a piece of code here in a php file where I have this:

```
  <?

     if(mysql_num_rows($c1=mysql_query("SELECT id_articulo, nombre, url, valido FROM landing_articulos WHERE 1 ORDER BY valido DESC, nombre ASC"))){

while($f1=mysql_fetch_array($c1)){
    ?>
      <div style="float:left; width:32%; padding-left:0px; color:#ef5000; font-weight:bold; margin:5px;"><p><a href="/at-<?=$f1["url"]?>_<?=$f1["id_articulo"]?>.html" target="_blank"><strong><?=$f1["nombre"];?></strong></a> <a href="editar_nuevapagina.php?id=<?=$f1["id_articulo"]?>"><img src="imagenes/lapiz.png" width="15" height="15" border="0"/></a> </a> <a href="javascript:eliminar_art('<?=$f1["id_articulo"]?>');"><img src="imagenes/delete.png" width="15" height="15" border="0"/></a> <? if($f1["valido"]=='0')echo ' - SIN VALIDAR';?></p></div>

<?
   }
 }
?>
```

This build an url like  xxxxxxx/at-p78_5.html where p78 is the $f1['url'] and the 5 is the id_articulo.

In my htaccess I have this:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On

       RewriteRule ^iniciarsesion acceso_xxxx.php

       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxx\.es$ [NC]  
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxx.es/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

       RewriteRule ^ce-(.+)_([0-9]+).html web_provincia.php?id=$2&url=$1 [L]
       RewriteRule ^at-(.+)_([0-9]+).html web_nuevapagina.php?id=$2&url=$1 [L]
       RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+).html categoria.php?idcat=$1&url=$2 [L]
       RewriteRule ^(.+).html provincia.php?url=$1 [L]
       RewriteRule ^art-(.+).html nuevapagina.php?url=$1 [L]


       RewriteRule ^articulo(.+)-(.+).html articulo.php?idart=$1&url=$2

       RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?xxxx\.es/ [NC]
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC]
       RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ /no_imagen.jpe [L]

       ErrorDocument 404 http://www.xxxx.es

       </IfModule>

       <IfModule mod_gzip.c>
           mod_gzip_on Yes
           mod_gzip_item_include file \.html$
           mod_gzip_item_include file \.php$
           mod_gzip_item_include file \.css$
           mod_gzip_item_include file \.js$
           mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/javascript$
           mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript$
           mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
           mod_gzip_item_include handler ^application/x-httpd-php
           mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
     </IfModule>

     <Files *.css>
         SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      </Files>

      <Files *.js>
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
      </Files>

         # Expires Headers - 2678400s = 31 days
        <ifmodule mod_expires.c>
          ExpiresActive On
          ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
          ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
          ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2678400 seconds"
          ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2678400 seconds"
          ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2678400 seconds"
          ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 518400 seconds"
          ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
          ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 2678400 seconds"
       </ifmodule>
     # Cache Headers
      <ifmodule mod_headers.c>
     # Cache specified files for 31 days
       Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, public"
     # Cache HTML files for a couple hours
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, private, must-revalidate"
     # Cache PDFs for a day
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
     # Cache Javascripts for 31 days
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2678400, private"
   </ifmodule>
```

And on my web_nuevapagina.php I have this:

```
  <?php

          if (mysql_num_rows($cfila = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM landing_articulos WHERE id_articulo='" . $_GET["id"] . "' LIMIT 1"))) {
$fila = mysql_fetch_array($cfila);
           echo 'Hola Prueba';
 } else {
     echo 'Falla';
     header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Permanently');
     header('Location: /');
     exit;
}

if ($fila['url'] != '') {
    $urlbuena = '/art-' . $fila["url"] . '.html';
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $urlbuena) {
       header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: ' . $urlbuena);
    }
  } else {
     header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Permanently');
     header('Location: /');
     exit;
  }
```

And finally, I have the nuevapagina.php where I have this piece of code

```
     if (mysql_num_rows($cfila = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM landing_articulos WHERE url='" . $_GET["url"] . "' AND valido>'0' LIMIT 1"))) {
         $fila = mysql_fetch_array($cfila);
      } else {
           header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Permanently');
           header('Location: /');
           exit;
      }
      if ($fila['url'] != '') {
          $urlbuena = '/art-' . $fila["url"] . '.html';
      if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != $urlbuena) {
          header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
          header('Location: ' . $urlbuena);
       }
      } else {
         header('HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Permanently');
         header('Location: /');
         exit;
      }
```

So, how can I fix it?, it goes to the root path and don't show what I want. Hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: Where is the htaccess and destination file located?

Comment: On the / path. Thanks

Comment: what exactly happenes when you go to /at-p78-5.html?

Comment: It goes to the main url and not where I should go.

Comment: Main url? do you mean the hompage?

Comment: Yes, homepage, sorry.

Comment: Do you have any other RewriteRules ?

Comment: I have added the rewrite rules of my htaccess right now.

Comment: Yes, i reviewed it. but your rules look as if they should work. Can you post your full htaccess?

Comment: I did it right now, I have places the whole htaccess

Comment: Any idea? @starkeen . Thanks so much

Comment: You are outputing text before headers. You are using code that can be exploited using sql injection. You are sending temporary redirect codes with "Permanent redirect" text. Anyway.... can you open the developer console of your browser, go to the network tab of that, and then go to whatever the start url is and pay attention to the requests that are made. What response code, headers and body are sent back.

Comment: In your case, you seem to be sometimes testing with permanent redirects too. Don't do this. Permanent redirects are cached, and as such if you make a mistake, the browser will remember the previous redirect and prevents the first request from ever being made.